# What's the purpose of using Function.call.apply in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was browsing through the [JavaScript Garden](http://javascriptgarden.info/) when I stumbled upon the Function.call.apply hack which is used to create "fast, unbound wrappers". It says:

> Another trick is to use both call and apply together to create fast, unbound wrappers.
>
> ```
> function Foo() {}
>
> Foo.prototype.method = function(a, b, c) {
>     console.log(this, a, b, c);
> };
>
> // Create an unbound version of "method" 
> // It takes the parameters: this, arg1, arg2...argN
> Foo.method = function() {
>
>     // Result: Foo.prototype.method.call(this, arg1, arg2... argN)
>     Function.call.apply(Foo.prototype.method, arguments);
> };
> ```

What I don't understand is why bother using Function.call.apply when Function.apply would suffice. After all, both of them are semantically equivalent.

Comment: I did post a link to the [JavaScript Garden](http://javascriptgarden.info/). If you want to jump directly to the section which contains the post, then click [here](http://javascriptgarden.info/#function.arguments).

Comment: tnx, - it seems that they imply this hack gives some speed up.. but, really, just **do not use it**.

Comment: @Aadit `Function.call.apply` and `Function.apply` can't be the same here because the former applies `Function.call` while the second tries to apply the `Function` constructor.  Details in my answer, but I'll bet if Ivo Wetzel came around to answer this it his would be far more eloquent and understandable.  This is rather deep stuff.  I agree that it's probably not something you should use unless you want colleagues to spend, oh I don't know, a _half hour_ trying to understand it. :)

Comment: I think `Function.call` is actually a bit misleading. It should really be `Function.prototype.call`, since `Function.call`could be overwritten. `Function` is just a function object after all. (Yes, this is hard to understand)

Comment: @Pubbaa80 Though `Function.call===Function.prototype.call` in the absence of nasty things, I totally agree with you. But note `JSON.stringify(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Function.prototype, "call"))` returns `{"writable":true,"enumerable":false,"configurable":true}` so the truly evil _can overwrite_ `Function.prototype.call` too.  Yikes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, `Function.call.apply` and `Function.apply` are not the same in this case.

Let's say the original caller invokes

```
Foo.method(t, x, y, z)
```

With call and apply together, as in the JavaScript Garden code. This executes

```
Function.call.apply(Foo.prototype.method, arguments);
```

which is (loosely, writing `arguments` in array-notation):

```
Function.call.apply(Foo.prototype.method, [t, x, y, z]);
```

which invokes `Function.call` with `this==Foo.prototype.method`:

```
Foo.prototype.method.call(t, x, y, z)
```

which calls `Foo.prototype.method` with `this` set to `t` and arguments `x`, `y`, and `z`.  Sweet.  Just like in the comments.  We have successfully made a wrapper.

Now suppose you left said just `Function.apply` instead of `Function.call.apply`, which you claim is semantically equivalent.  You would have

```
Function.apply(Foo.prototype.method, arguments);
```

which is (loosely)

```
Function.apply(Foo.prototype.method, [t, x, y, z]);
```

which calls the function `Function` (ugh!) with `this` set to `Foo.prototype.method` and arguments `t`, `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Not the same at all.

Comment: But what is the purpose of such wrapping ?

Comment: The purpose is to call `Foo.prototype.method` without it being bound to an instance of `Foo`.  Instead you pass in _your own_ value to be used as the value of `this` within `Foo.prototype.method`. Why would you do this?  Maybe you want to do some functional programming and the function you want to map or reduce or filter happens to be a bound method.  If you don't want it bound to an object, you call an "unbound wrapper."  This is strange terminology though, because you're ultimately binding this method to your own object (but you can ignore it....)

Comment: Ok, from what I understood the following statements are equivalent:

    Function.call.apply(Foo.prototype.method, arguments);
    Foo.prototype.method.apply(arguments[0], Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

Both of them can be substituted to create unbound wrappers. However, the first method is shorter, faster and more intuitive. Awesome!

Answer (score 4):

It means you can use the methods from an object on another one.

A good example is the arguments variable all functions have, it's like an array but not an array so you can call array's methods on it thus:

```
Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ",");
```

Comment: But what does the `apply` bit do in the original question?

Comment: @CameronSkinner: a function object's `apply` method executes that function, treating the first argument as `this` in that execution and the second argument as `arguments`. `fn.apply(a, [b, c])` is equivalent to `fn.call(a, b, c)`.