# Passing Arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to understand the following behaviour because the explanation on this site  [javascript garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/) is not enough for me.

It would be much appreciated if you could give me a clear explanation about 
the questions which are in the inline comments.

Here the example:

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.method = function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(this, a, b, c);
};

Foo.method = function() {
    Function.call.apply(Foo.prototype.method, arguments);
};


Foo.prototype.method(1,2,3) // Foo { method=function()} 1 2 3 //this output is obvious
Foo.method(1,2,3)  // Number {} 2 3 undefined // I want understand why the first argument is a number and the last one is undefined
```

Comment: The questions are in the inline comments in his code.

Comment: I think you are asking about what's discussed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459769/whats-the-purpose-of-using-function-call-apply-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Function.call.apply(Foo.prototype.method, arguments);
```

is the same as

```
Foo.prototype.method.call(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], ...);
```

which, in your case, is the same as:

```
Foo.prototype.method.call(1, 2, 3);
```

This means, inside `Foo.prototype.method`, `this` will refer to `1`, [but as `this` always has to reference an object](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_10.4.3) (in non-strict environment), `1` is converted to a `Number` object.

The last value is `undefined` because you are effectively only passing `2` and `3` (two arguments) to the method (instead of three).

So in the end, the code is doing something similar to this:

```
var obj = new Number(1);
obj.method = Foo.prototype.method;
obj.method(2,3);
```

Comment: Note that on strict mode, `this` is no longer implicitly converted to number, e.g.: `(function () {'use strict'; return typeof this; }).call(1) == 'number'`