# Purpose of this idiom in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What might be the purpose of the following idiom?

```
Function.apply.call(fn, console, args);
```

I have never seen apply being "called" before.

Comment: [MDN apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: is `Function` here a placeholder for an actual function, or are you talking about the actual [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)?

Comment: @epascarello I think the question is about the use of `apply` _and_ `call` together, not what `apply` is

Comment: I missed the `call(),` morning coffee has not kicked in.

Comment: Certainly doesn't [seem rare](https://code.openhub.net/search?s=%22.apply.call%22) in usage

Comment: @James the actual Function constructor.

Comment: More information and discussion on [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459769/whats-the-purpose-of-using-function-call-apply-in-javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly not idiomatic :-) Let's see what it does:

- `Function.apply` is the `Function.prototype.apply` method - the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) inherits it.
- this method gets [`.call`ed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), with the `fn` as the `this` value, the `console` as the first argument, and `args` as the second.

So this should be equivalent to `fn.apply(console, args)`, which invokes `fn` (probably a `console` method) on the `console` object with a dynamic `args` list.

So why is this done? Because `Function.apply.call(fn, console, args)` is not exactly equivalent to `fn.apply(console, args)`! It only is when `fn.apply === Function.apply`, which might not be the case.
It's unlikely that somebody would have overridden the `.apply` property - and if he did it was his fault -, but there is a real-world issue: `fn` objects that don't inherit from `Function.prototype` even though they are callable. Such can happen in buggy implementations of host objects; and the best-known example is [Internet Explorer's `console` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5538972/1048572).

Answer (score 4):

To call a function, we need the 'function', 'this', and 'arguments'.

Using `Function.apply` or `Function.call` by themselves lets you specify 'this' and 'arguments' but not the function to call because they use their own `this` as the function, so we need an extra layer to set that 'this' value.

You could instead say:

```
fn.apply(console, args);
```

but this won't work if `fn.apply` has been overwritten.