# Why does this result?

Tags: javascript, return

I recently watched a video where the teacher demonstrated that the javascript code

```
alert.call.apply(function(a) {return a}, [1,2])
```

results always in "2". So here is my question: Why??

I could not find any explination why this result is returned.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: `alert.call.apply(function(a) {return a}, [1,2])` -> `(function (a) { return a; }).call(1, 2)` -> `(function (a) { return a; })(2)` -> 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of using Function.call.apply in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459769/whats-the-purpose-of-using-function-call-apply-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

This code is just too clever!
But wait, the following code will produce the same result:

```
console.log.call.apply(function(a) {return a}, [1,2])
```

Here is what's happening: `apply()`'s first parameter is a '`this`', the second is a list of argument. It then calls the function `console.log.call` with those parameters, which logically is equivalent to:

```
(function(a) {return a}).call(1,2)
```

This code produces the same result and is a little bit easier to understand - we are using `call()` on the unnamed function. `call()`'s parameters are a '`this`' object followed by arguments. In this case '`this`' is `1`, and the argument is `2`, so the function gets called with `a` assigned to `2` (the `1` is not used in the function which is unbound). So this will always return `2`, since it is simply returning the second item in the list.

But what is the role of `alert`, and why can we substitute any function name there? Well, it seems that there is a single `call()` function that is shared between all prototypes. You can verify that hypothesis by running

```
alert.call === console.log.call
true
```

So it doesn't matter if we use `alert`, `console.log`, or nothing, we are always using the same `call()` function.